# Convert String datetime to Date not working Java Android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, converters

I don't know why I can't convert a String to a Date in Java Android. I got error when I try

The error :

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Apr 30 00:12:13 GMT+02:00 2021"
```

My code :

```
String datestr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UPDATED_AT)); // Fri Apr 30 00:12:13 GMT+02:00 2021
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);
myDate = dateFormat.parse(datestr);
```

---

**Edit:**

I'm up to date now (I think):

I convert all my Date to

> OffsetDateTime currentDate = OffsetDateTime.now()

That gives me :

> 2021-04-30T02:14:49.067+02:00

Then If this date is a String and I want to convert it to OffsetDateTime :

```
String datestr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UPDATED_AT)); // 2021-04-30T02:14:49.067+02:00
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").withLocale( Locale.US );
OffsetDateTime myDate = OffsetDateTime.parse( datestr , f );
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
OffsetDateTime
.parse( 
    "Fri Apr 30 00:12:13 GMT+02:00 2021" , 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu" )
    .withLocale( Locale.US ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2021-04-30T00:12:13+02:00

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a formatting pattern to match your input text. Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

Note the `Locale`, to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in translating the name of day & month, capitalization, abbreviation, and so on.

```java
String input = "Fri Apr 30 00:12:13 GMT+02:00 2021";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your input represents a moment, a point on the timeline, as seen in the wall-clock time of an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone. Therefore, parse as a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> odt.toString() = 2021-04-30T00:12:13+02:00

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image]